# Hair won't render in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I just followed [Andrew Price's video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEnCsvcvX8k) on how to render hair in cycles, and I have followed every single direction, but no hair gets rendered. Is something not enabled or activated?

It is almost like it is trying to render with the particles grit there.

[image]
[image]

Here is the [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/23841).

Answer (score 8):

You may need to enable experimental features in the render tab for Cycles to render hair.

If you have an older version of blender and want to render hair on the GPU, you'll need to get a newer build from [builder.blender.org](http://builder.blender.org) or [graphicall.org](http://graphicall.org)

[image: Experimental Feature Set]

Comment: You may need to specify _how_ to do this.

Comment: In the last blender release (2.68a) it's already implemented. You don't need to download a build . The official version of blender, downloadable on blender.org, have already this feature.

Comment: I have the newest version but it wont work for some reason and yes it is set to experimental

Comment: @NikkiPark Could you upload your blendfile or some screenshots of your particle settings? Right now it could be many things and we can't do much more than speculate.

Comment: Here is the file. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/23841

Answer (score 4):

It's probably because your particles are too small. You can see in your image that they *are* being rendered, but they're tiny.

The settings have changed since BG made his tutorial. There's now an additional factor, *Scale*, which, if I recall, is by default set to 0.05. Scale this up to 1 (or scale the root down by a factor of 20) and you should see better results.

I had this same issue when porting a Blender 2.66 file to Blender 2.67 – suddenly, all my hair was "gone!" But setting this value correctly should fix you up real good.

Comment: how do I change the size of the particles!!!!?????

Comment: @Nikki see my edit.

Comment: Where do I change the scale?

Comment: In the particle settings, next to *Root* and *Tip*.

Comment: I scaled it up to 20 and it i still small. Should I go for a higher scaling?

Comment: Thanks It is working so well but how do I increase the ammount of hairs

Comment: Change *Number* at the top.

Comment: @WChargin when using particle mode, you cannot add more particles with the *Number* property. Try using the *Add* brush in particle mode.

Comment: @gandalf3 true; good point. Could that have an impact on the scale as well? Try *Free Edit*.

Comment: You can simply add hair with the children's hair mode. In you particle panel you have a children menu where you can increase the render number for "multiply" the number of hair

Comment: @NikkiPark if this is the correct answer for your question, please mark it as such for future googlers with the same problem

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, you have to be out of Particle Mode before you render or the hair will not appear. I'm using 2.71

Comment: @someonewithpc Did you test it? It's not the issue in this particular question, but he is correct that hair doesn't seem to be rendered in particle edit mode.

Comment: @someonewithpc could you please elaborate so all of us can learn?

Comment: Sorry; let's say that I wasn't in the best conditions yesterday...

Comment: I think because it will require to update for example the render if you are inside particle editor for hair (you can't change real time the look/combing of the hair)... so maybe they did choose to not put hair if you are editing hair.... 1.75a and it works this way.

Answer (score -1):

Go to modifier properties and click on *Convert to Mesh*!